# Localize a date

Tags: datetime, i18n-l10n

How can I localize a date? I use PHP to output a custom date format, and I want to translate the components, such as the name of the month.

I am using the following code. Is there a better code I should use with Drupal?

```
global $language;
if ($language->language == 'ar') {
  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_CA.UTF-8');
  echo strftime("%B %e, %G");
}
else {
  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_CA.UTF-8');
  print(date("l,F j, Y");
}
```

Comment: where do you use this code?

Comment: inside the block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7.x), the following format character are localized by Drupal:

- %A (In English, AM and PM)
- %a (am, pm)
- %e (e.g. UTC, Atlantic/Azores)
- %D (e.g. Mon, Sun)
- %l (e.g. Monday, Sunday)
- %M (e.g. Jan, Dec)
- %T (e.g. EST, MDT)
- %F (e.g. January, December)

Notice also that on admin/config/regional/date-time/locale, it is possible to change the long/medium/short formats used from `format_date()`.

[image: screenshot]

Clicking on the "edit" link, you can change those formats for every language.

[image: screenshot]

Instead of the code you are using, you should simply use:

```
$date_str = format_date(time(), 'short');  // the short format, such as 01/16/2013 - 20:37
```

```
$date_str = format_date(time(), 'medium');  // the medium format, such as Wed, 01/16/2013 - 20:37
```

```
$date_str = format_date(time(), 'long');  // the long format, such as Wednesday, January 16, 2013 - 20:37
```

The effective format used for the long, short, and medium formats are the ones set on admin/config/regional/date-time/locale for the language currently used to display the page.

Comment: What should I do if I already have a date value? I tried `date_format(strtotime($date));` but it does not work!